# Getting messages Rest::norest and Divide::indet from ContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, bugs, warning-messages

<sub>**Note:** The bug described in this post is found in Mathematica version 9 and seems to have been fixed in version 10.</sub>

Ok I don't know if it's a bug or what, but here's what I found:

If I use this function:

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[2*Pi*z] + Cos[2*Pi*y] + Cos[2*Pi*x], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

I get this error:

> Rest::norest: Cannot take the rest of expression {} with length zero. >>

I have found that this issue is sometimes due to a need to use a numeric function. So I used:

```
ContourPlot3D[N[Cos[2*Pi*z] + Cos[2*Pi*y] + Cos[2*Pi*x]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

And I get this error:

> Divide::indet: Indeterminate expression 0./0. encountered. >>
>   Range::range: Range specification in Range[3.,3.,0.] does not have appropriate bounds. >>

I also tried:

```
ContourPlot3D[Cos[2*Pi*z?NumericQ] + Cos[2*Pi*y?NumericQ] + Cos[2*Pi*x?NumericQ], 
  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

But I get:

> ContourPlot3D::valuef: N[Cos[2 π z?NumericQ]+Cos[2 π y?NumericQ]+Cos[2 π x?NumericQ]] must be a numerical function. >>

However, if I try any of this:

```
ContourPlot3D[N[Cos[z] + Cos[y] + Cos[x]], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0,2*Pi}]
ContourPlot3D[Cos[z] + Cos[y] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 2*Pi}, {y, 0, 2*Pi}, {z, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

I get no error what-so-ever. But the error with `NumericQ` persists. I'd also like to point out that the `NumericQ` error is the only one preventing me from getting the 3D graphics.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Comment: I Just  added `== 0` and no such error now. `ContourPlot3D[Cos[2*Pi*z] + Cos[2*Pi*y] + Cos[2*Pi*x] == 0, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]` gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUlil.png)

Comment: Is it really important what is going on?

Comment: As tot the `?NumericQ` issue: You should not normally use a pattern test in a function *call*. You are confusing this with restrictions you put on function parameters in a function *definition*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is going on?

By `Trace`-ing the `ContourPlot3D`, I found the warning (on my MMA) comes from a function `` System`ProtoPlotDump`findextreme `` (Hereafter, the context `` System`ProtoPlotDump` `` will be omitted for readability):

```
findextreme[{f_,
                {x_, xmin_, xmax_},
                {y_, ymin_, ymax_},
                {z_, zmin_, zmax_}
            }] := Quiet[
        Check[Through[{Min, Max}[Re[Table[f,
                                            {x, xmin, xmax},
                                            {y, ymin, ymax},
                                            {z, zmin, zmax}
                                         ]]]], None]]

findextreme[_] := None
```

This `findextreme` seems to be designed for finding the minimal and maximal value of the inputted function `Cos[2 π z] + Cos[2 π y] + Cos[2 π x]` over the plotting volume. But for OP's function, we have:

```
Table[Cos[2 π z] + Cos[2 π y] + Cos[2 π x], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}]
```

> {{{3, 3}, {3, 3}}, {{3, 3}, {3, 3}}}

Thus `findextreme` evaluated to `{3, 3}`.

Now, by checking the `Stack[__]` when the warning message arises, we can see there is a piece of code in the definition of a local variable `defaultlabels$`:

```
Charting`SimplePadding[
    N[Rest[Most[
                Range[Sequence @@ extreme, Subtract @@ Reverse[extreme]/(3 + 1)]
               ]]]]
```

where `extreme` is the result returned by `findextreme`. So the `Range[...]` part in the above code evaluated to

```
Range[3, 3, 0]
```

, or when `N` is applied on the inputted function:

```
Range[3., 3., 0.]
```

The former case goes to `Rest[{}]` and rises the `Rest::norest` warning, and the latter one itself rises the `Divide::indet` warning.

### Temporary solution

By re-defining the `findextreme` function (*i.e.* using a random step size), I am able to avoid the problem described in OP:

```
Clear[System`ProtoPlotDump`findextreme]

System`ProtoPlotDump`findextreme[{System`ProtoPlotDump`f_,
            {System`ProtoPlotDump`x_,
                System`ProtoPlotDump`xmin_, System`ProtoPlotDump`xmax_},
            {System`ProtoPlotDump`y_,
                System`ProtoPlotDump`ymin_, System`ProtoPlotDump`ymax_},
            {System`ProtoPlotDump`z_,
                System`ProtoPlotDump`zmin_, System`ProtoPlotDump`zmax_}
            }] := Quiet[Check[Through[{Min, Max}[Re[Table[
                            System`ProtoPlotDump`f,
                            {System`ProtoPlotDump`x,
                                System`ProtoPlotDump`xmin, System`ProtoPlotDump`xmax,
                                (System`ProtoPlotDump`xmax - System`ProtoPlotDump`xmin)/RandomReal[{2, 3}]
                            },
                            {System`ProtoPlotDump`y,
                                System`ProtoPlotDump`ymin, System`ProtoPlotDump`ymax,
                                (System`ProtoPlotDump`ymax - System`ProtoPlotDump`ymin)/RandomReal[{2, 3}]
                            },
                            {System`ProtoPlotDump`z,
                                System`ProtoPlotDump`zmin, System`ProtoPlotDump`zmax,
                                (System`ProtoPlotDump`zmax - System`ProtoPlotDump`zmin)/RandomReal[{2, 3}]
                            }
                            ]]]], None]]

System`ProtoPlotDump`findextreme[_] := None
```

### Warning

The `defaultlabels$` is used in code:

```
legendfront$ = 
            Legending`PlotLegendParser["Generic"][ContourPlot3D, legendData$, 
            plotlegends$];
    Legended[plot$, legendfront$]
```

which suggests it might relate to automatic legend for `ContourPlot3D`, thus choosing the unit step size might has its reason. So re-defining `findextreme` may cause unpredictable consequence.

Comment: Have anyone else tested this solution?

Comment: @LucianoRobino This is the what I want to know... Anyway does it work for you?

Comment: It work in my side for both cases.

Although I was afraid to try it due to the unpredictable consequences for this minimal example it works fine. I'm not sure if I'll try it in the original file where the issue pop up

Comment: @LucianoRobino Great! :D And thanks for accepting.

Comment: @LucianoRobino I think as long as you don't use legend on the outputted graphics, it will be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I got a result using Mathematica 9.01 . It is possible that you have an older version or missing libraries. Install flash in your computer to see if this might have to do with the graphic diver.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, my 9.0.1 home edition gives same warning as OP said.

Comment: @Silvia, Jose: Could be an OS-dependent issue. Jose's screenshot appears to be taken on Windows, while I do get the warnings on my Mac.

Comment: @RahulNarain I'm on Windows 8 x64 ..

Comment: Provide here the results of SystemInformation[] It will be interesting to compared the results from Sulvia and Rahul

Comment: I've `Trace`-d down to the source of the problem, will compose a post after lunch -- if no other answers appear then ;)

Comment: My error appeared on Debian Jessie